# Sending AT commands from an embedded system to a Fastrack Supreme Wavecom Module

Tags: embedded, client, pic, at-command

I have an embedded system that controls a motor using pwm and some other things, I send commands through a serial connection, which is connected to a Fastrack Wavecom Supreme GSM Module. However, the module connected to the embedded system (the client), fails to send the message to the server module.

I have been able to send messages back and forth between the two wavecom modules, however, when I try and send from my PIC18F45k22 to the wavecom module, it fails.

Any ideas of what could be going wrong?

Comment: I believe the Fastrack Supreme has 12V level RS232 - are you level shifting your PIC TTL serial (eg using a MAX232)?

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what type of serial communication you are using.  For instance, if you are using the PIC's SPI module you may be sampling on the wrong edge of the clock.  There are at least 2 common SPI modes widely used and 4 all together. If you are using the PIC's UART there are "a whole bucket full" of setting that may be off.  Speed, number of bits, in band signaling, out of band signaling, parity, ect.